# Как сделать интервал в тексте при его наборе для отправки формы в Php?

Tags: php

Я понимаю что есть определённая форма, для отправки данных карты, но в данный момент мне переделывать не хочеться, и возник вопрос а можно ли просто тут обозначить интервалы при написании цифр.

```
<div class="contact-form__input-wrapper contact-form__input-wrapper_card">
        <input name="card" type="text" class="contact-form__input contact-form__input_card"
               placeholder="Напишите ваш номер карты" minlength="16" maxlength="16">
      </div>
```

Comment: Понятно ровно ничего

Comment: Затупил при отправке, прошу прощения ....

Comment: Всё равно ничего не ясно..... что за интервалы, причём тут отправка формы? что значит "обозначить интервалы"?

Comment: У меня сайт для отправки формы в телеграм, там есть строка  "Напишите ваш номер карты" .  Я хочу что бы при заполнении в строке на сайте , было вот так 2222  2222  2222 2222 , а не вот так 2222222222222222 .

Comment: на php это не реализовать. Вам нужен скрипт на javascript, который изменяет введённые данные на данные с интервалами в цифрах

Comment: @АртурРябушкин  https://webstool.ru/jquery.maskedinput.html    ..... можно и просто на js ....... к выхе тут этим не делается

Comment: Разобрался, вы мне очень помогли !

Comment: Оффтоп, конечно, но как же до боли в зубах доставляет это ваше "Напишите ваш номер карты". По-русски лучше звучало бы "Напишите номер вашей карты" ))

Comment: Ахахахаха блин щас изменю, я как то не приглядывался к этому, или просто с русским проблемы....